# PHP : howto create links from results

Tags: php, joomla

I am decent in PHP coding but i am not sure how this requirement is generally acheived.

I don't have a piece of code to show since i can start coding easily once i get the logic of how this is generally done.

Need some pointers on how to start...

I am writing a website that would show up the search results fetched from the database like item1,item2,item3 etc.,

how do i create separate links to each of these items as fetched from the database so that it would look like there are separate links available to these items that can be bookmarked or referred easily for the users.?

Something like mywebsite.com/showItem.php?id=232323232 is not what i want, Instead i want like mywebsite.com/item1 , mywebsite.com/item2 , mywebsite.com/item3 for each of the items that can be viewed separately when clicked or bookmarked. )

I see some websites does it easily, not sure how they do.

Kindly give me some pointers on the starting point so that i get it done.

Note: I am using Joomla 3 for my website just in case if that adds any value for this requirement. thanks.

Comment: You said Joomla 3, do you want the answer in PHP or Joomla?

Comment: Not sure if there are any settings in Joomla3 that does this easily. But, i notice there is a "SEO-friendly-URL" setting and i have chosen 'yes' for that. Thats not giving what i want to. so i guess it needs some scripting to achieve, if I'm not wrong. You can share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Joomla but i can tell you about how to implement in PHP
What you want is called `"SEO-friendly URLs"`. You will get lot of tutorials on google for this.

Overview:

```
1) Use htaccess to convert normal URLs into SEO-friendly.
2) Manipulate / modify existing URLs in application to new-architecture.
3) In php, append prefix "item"(you can use anything here, i have specified item just with the reference of the example you have stated.)
```

I would like to remind you again that this is just an overview of the steps that you need to follow to achieve what you want. Just put some efforts and i am sure you will get it done...

Comment: Kool. Thanks for giving the starting point. I referred here http://tutorial.world.edu/web-development/create-seo-friendly-urls-rewrite-htaccess-mod_rewrite/ which gives me the idea of how to do this. I will take it from here. thanks.